Is angular-highcharts npm package compaitble with highcharts >= 7 for Angular 9.1.13 migration?
I am migrating angular 8 app to angular 9.1.13, highcharts are implemented in my app and I am trying to update highcharts as well. For that I am updating highcharts from 6.2.0 to v7.2.2 and angular-highcharts from 8.0.2 to v9.0.11.
But I am getting a lot of typescript type errors.
Even after fixing breaking changes, charts are not being rendered on the UI but just a div is showing with black background. Although angular-highcharts v9.0.11 is working fine with highcharts 6.2.0.
this is how the chart is rendered when I select all the text on the page:

Is the angular-highcharts package supporting highcharts versions greater than 6?

Angular-Highcharts is not an official Highcharts integration with Angular. If you want to use an official integration, you should use the highcharts-angular package, which you can find at these links:
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular
In the table there's information about which version of Node, Angular and Highcharts fits which version of angular integration package.
Version Node     Angular    Highcharts
4.0.0   >=16.14  >=16.0.0   >=11.0.0
3.1.2   >=14.13  >=15.0.0   >=10.3.3
3.0.0   >=14.13  >=9.0.0    >=8.0.0
<2.10.0 >=6.10.2 >=6.0.0    >=6.0.0


Dominik i know the official package, i just want to confirm about the angular-highcharts as I have a lot of chart components so have to revamp all the code for new package.
